Resolve-DnsName whoami.ultradns.net fails but nslookup whoami.ultradns.net suceeds? (powershell)
I was cleaning out some old code and decided to update a few things for powershell use when I came across this issue... In powershell (or a command prompt window) in Windows 10 I can do this with nslookup and get this:
nslookup whoami.ultradns.net
Server:  dns.sse.cisco.com
Address:  208.67.222.222

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    whoami.ultradns.net
Address:  255.255.255.255

But, in powershell if I use Resolve-DnsName I get this (with -Type A --- the default type for nslookup is type A):
Resolve-DnsName whoami.ultradns.net -Type A

Name                                           Type   TTL   Section    IPAddress
----                                           ----   ---   -------    ---------
whoami.ultradns.net                            A      0     Answer     255.255.255.255

Notice how with Resolve-DnsName the 'IPAddress' is '255.255.255.255' which is the 'Non-authoritative answer' that was given with nslookup. But what I need to get from Resolve-DnsName is the 'Address:' (that '208.67.222.222' address in the nslookup example) but its no where to be found from Resolve-DnsName (even if I drill into the .psobject.Members... etc...).
So, how do I get the 'Address:' with Resolve-DnsName? Is it me or what?

I’m pretty sure 208.67.222.222  is the address of the dns server your machine is configured to use, not the ip address of whoami.ultradns.net

Well, yes the 208.67.222.222 is the dns server that was configured on the machine. But that's not the point. The point is that it shows with nslookup but doesn't show  with Resolve-DnsName and I'm pretty sure it should. This whomi server is supposed to return the IP of the DNS server making the request (which in this example give is 208.67.222.222) and ultradns has verified that for me and its been up for years for that purpose and it does that properly on other systems I've checked it on so far if nslookup is used but doesn't do it with Resolve-DnsName and I'm pretty sure it should.

Resolve-DnsName returns a list of objects of type Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.DnsRecord_A which don't have a property that gives the name of the dns server used to resolve the record. You might want to look at Get-DnsClientServerAddress instead if you want to retreive dns settings (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/get-dnsclientserveraddress?view=windowsserver2022-ps for details)

Ahh Ha! Thanks for the reply. That explains it. I never knew that before. Was using the nslookup in the past to detect man-in-the-middle redirection of DNS, if it was redirected from that configured on the systems then the different DNS IP would show and I would know dns queries were being hijacked. But after some further consultation, your reply, and experimentation I find out Resolve-DnsName returns 255.255.255.255 only if the system configured DNS is being used for the queries like it should be if its not being hijacked and redirected.
